# Windows: Deleting folder common in multiple sub-folders

Tags: windows, cmd, rmdir

Is there a way to do this?  I have a folder structure as such:

```
A/
    Folder/
B/
    Folder/
C/
    Folder/
D/
    Folder/
```

And I want to delete all of the "Folder/"s, along with all of their contents.  My first guess was

```
rmdir /S /Q *\Folder
```

but received an error on the *.  This has come up a few times in the past days, so I figured I'd get the more efficient way than going into each folder, because that wasn't fun.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this ?

`for /D %i in ("C:\Directory\*") do RD /S /Q "%i"`

Put double % if you want to do this in batch file

Comment: This doesn't cater for the 'common' folders in a tree.

Answer (score 0):

This should display the rd command for every directory that matches the `folde?` filespec under the current tree.

The wildcard is necessary so check the output before removing the `echo`

```
@echo off
for /d /r %%a in (folde?) do echo rd /s /q "%%a"
pause
```